# Popup for a view help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

Rails 2.3.5 (work server, no choice to be on Rails 3).   Currently I'm still using Prototype but just went through also adding JQuery (noconflict) to experiment with it's UI Dialog.  I'm a newb with no javascript or JQuery experience and a few months Rails experience.

I have an index page that lists 'teams'.   The listings don't show all the information and have text fields truncated.   So, on each 'team' listing I have a show and edit link going to a popup:

```
<%= link_to "Team_Details", {:controller => 'teams', :action => 'show', :id => t.id},
popup => ['show','toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,
menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,autosize=yes'] %>
```

Where I'm stuck is:

- having the popup open center screen
- making the popup auto-size
- The link_to title doesn't work (seems to be
  over-written by the view title)
- The general look isn't great (and no animation for open/close)

I tried getting this to work in a JQuery UI Dialog but I only got as far as an empty dialog window opening.  I thought being able to open a view into a popup would be pretty common where there would be a lot of Google info out there but I'm not having any luck tonight.  A lot of the information I found is about displaying the contents of a hidden div in the UI Dialog.

I guess I'm wondering what direction to go here?   I just want to pass an :id param to a view and have that view display in a popup.  If JQuery UI Dialog is a good way to go, is there a simple usage example out there somewhere for something like this?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use unobstrusive javascript with the jQuery's UI lightbox or with:

http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

If you use the latest, don't forget to put layout to false.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to figure that out now.  In there examples, you have to define each link in the script which I don't see working very well for a index page list.  I've been looking at Topup too.  It's twice as big but simply works be class names so you only need a single script line for all your links.

Comment: In my app, I have a list of user. Clicking on their pic displays a popup with details. My only js is: 'jQuery(".showdetails").colorbox();'
and the code is:           <a href="<%= url_for :controller => 'home', :action => 'details', :type => "team", :id => member.id %>" class="showdetails"><%= image_tag member.picture.url(:small) %></a>. See here: http://phdtalent.com/home/about_us

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else every looks for help with the link_to popup helper, the biggest problem I found was that if the user clicks back on the browser without closing the popup, the popup will loose focus and go behind the browser.   Then if a new popup is open, it would load into that existing popup window.   That seems like it has an extremely high chance of confusing a user because they might just think a new popup never opened.   To add to this problem, IE 6/7/8 has a bug in it's behavior for a window.onblur event.  The bug will close the window when the content changes.   So, if you allow a user to switch between show & edit in the poup window, that change will close the popup in IE.

I found script (w/ IE onblur fix for IE 6/7/8) will take care of everything:

From Vladimir Kelman
http://pro-thoughts.blogspot.com/2006/10/incorrect-behavior-of-windowonblur.html

```
<head>
     <script type="text/javascript">
          var active_element;
          var bIsMSIE;

          function initiateSelfClosing() {
              if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
                  active_element = document.activeElement;
                  document.onfocusout = closeWnd;
                  bIsMSIE = true;
                  }
                    else { window.onblur = closeWnd; }
                  }

                  function closeWnd() {
                  if (window.opener != null) {
                  if (bIsMSIE && (active_element != document.activeElement)) {
                    active_element = document.activeElement;
                  }
                      else {
                      window.close();
                  }
              }
          }
      </script>

<body onload="initiateSelfClosing()">

stuff

<body/>
```